# Awk only match first match of line in multiline text

Tags: regex, macos, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to match a specific number (`06:00`) and (`9:00`) if it's the first match on a line in a multi-line file. The problem it seems with my limited knowledge of awk is that I either get only the first match, or matches with the second number also. I would also like to tally up the resulting matches count and the end too, but since it's not matching correctly I haven't gotten that far.

```
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
Schedule in <08:00>:10 out <06:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:9 out <05:00>:0
Schedule in <07:00>:13 out <08:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <09:00>:0
Schedule in <09:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
Schedule in <07:00>:11 out <06:00>:0
```

I tried:

```
awk '/06/||/09/' schedule.txt

awk '$1 ~ /\<06/||/\<09/ {print $1}' schedule.txt
```

correct output:

```
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:9 out <05:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <09:00>:0
Schedule in <09:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
4 Total Matches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
awk '$3 ~ /<06/||/<09/ {print $0}' schedule.txt
#     ^                        ^
```

The key point is *by default* `awk` tokenizes each string into words separated by *spaces*. First "word" in `$1`, second in `$2` and so on. `$0` is the entire line.

Given one of your input lines:

```
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
<------> <> <--------> <-> <------->
   $1    $2    $3       $4    $5
<---------------------------------->
                 $0
```

I simply changed your `awk` program to test `$3` which appears to be the right field. And in case of matches, I print the whole line (`$0`).

<sub>As a side note, `print $0` might be shortened to `print`. Many commands/functions accepting strings in `awk` defaults to `$0`</sub>

---

With a few more "frills":

```
sh$ awk '$3 ~ /<06/||/<09/ {count++; print $0} END {printf("%d Total Matches\n", count) }' schedule.txt
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:9 out <05:00>:0
Schedule in <06:00>:12 out <09:00>:0
Schedule in <09:00>:12 out <06:00>:0
4 Total Matches
```

---

Finally, as @Jidder said below:

> *"This could all be reduced to :"*
>
> ```
> awk 'END {print x,"Total Matches"} $3~/0[69]:/&&++x'
> ```

Comment: @Hank As far as I can tell, the result is the _exact same_ you were expecting in your question.

Comment: That works. I can't believe how dumb I am or how close I was. If you could explain where I went wrong that would be great. Thanks

Comment: @Hank Of course I will. Just allow me the time for edit! ;) After that, is that suits you don't forget to vote up and/or accept. That's the way to say "thank you" here.

Comment: @Hank What about the explanation?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, awk '$3 ~ /<0[69]/' file is enough and more efficient, no need use || outside regex. and '\<' is word boundary, are you just looking for a literal '<'?

Comment: @lihao Obviouly some copy/paste stupidities here (`\<`). And of course they are better/more efficients solutions. As the OP is new to `awk` I just wanted to build on his knowledge. But your comment is very welcome! @Hank About counting, I think this has already been addressed in the answer. Check twice!

Comment: @Hank, by '|| outside regex', I meant two regexes combined by a logic OR. for 24-hour time, just use grouping and alternation: awk '$3 ~ /<(0[69]|18|21)/'

Comment: @Hank This could all be reduced to `awk 'END {print x,"Total Matches"}$3~/0[69]/&&++x'`

Comment: @Jidder, Good stuff. I might suggest one small thing, and that is including `:` after `[69]`, otherwise it would pick up `06` or `09` if one happens to be after the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a programming language that assumes you're looping through a file. We can take advantage of all the power available to us in awk including many of its text built in functions.

In Awk, you normally have well defined fields, but you don't have to. In your example, we can treat each line as a single field, and we can use `substr` to pull out the information we want. The time happens to be the 14 character position on the line (the first character in the first column is column 1 and not column 0). We want the five characters starting with position 14:

```
awk 'substr ($0, 14, 5) ~ /06|9:00/' test.txt
```

I compare these 5 characters to the regular expression `/06|9:00/`. If this boolean expression is true, the entire line is printed out.

This is the same as this more fully spelled out Awk program:

```
awk '{
    if ( substr ( $0, 14, 5 ) ~ /06|9:00/ ) {
        print $0
    }
}' test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution and explanation - it works great. Do you have any recommendations for learning more about awk. I didn't know about the `substr` option until now (+upvote if I could).